# Angular 2: Get Directive from ViewContainerRef

Tags: angular, typescript

Let's asume I have a directive "Lol".
Within a component, I can query content children annotated with Lol:

```
@ContentChildren(Lol)
private myLols: QueryList<Lol>;
```

Fine, when I do some component creation magic next to them, I can use ViewContainerRef:

```
@ContentChildren(Lol, {read: ViewContainerRef})
private myLols: QueryList<ViewContainerRef>;
```

What I want to do is:

- Create a component next to each lol-annotated element
- Bind the component to inputs of the Lol directive.

So I need both the ViewContainerRef as well as the Directive instance. Is there a way to get the ViewContainerRef from the Directive type or vice-versa?